# Work around for when jQuery UI doesn't account for margins when animating

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

-Hello, World!-

The title gives a pretty decent summary of what I am struggling with. I can't find any questions that have this exact problem, and I am unsure if I am doing something wrong.

When there is a bottom margin on an element and the blind animation is used to reveal it on the page, there is a jump the size of margin the end of `show()` and at the beginning of `hide()`.

There have been similar questions asked and people said to wrap the element in another div and then use hide/show on that, but that has not worked out for me.

What I have so far:

```js
$('#SelectDemo').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#SelectDemo').val() != undefined && $('#SelectDemo').val().endsWith('~')) {
    $('#ReactivateAlert').show('blind', {}, 1000);
  } else {
    $('#ReactivateAlert').hide('blind', {}, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="ReactivateAlert" style="display:none">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      When this alert box appears, the margin does not get included in the animation.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="col-form-label col-md-2" for="SelectDemo">Table</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="SelectDemo" name="SelectDemo">
      <option value="">--- Select a Test ---</option>
      <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
      <option value="Test2">Test2</option>
      <option value="Test3">Test3</option>
      <option value="Test4~">Test4~</option>
      <option value="Test5~">Test5~</option>
      <option value="Test6~">Test6~</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it. I've been stuck on this for awhile already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple work around: if you change show&hide with slideUp&slideDown and decrease the
duration the effect is nicer and there isn't any "jump".

```js
$('#SelectDemo').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#SelectDemo').val() != undefined && $('#SelectDemo').val().endsWith('~')) {
    $('#ReactivateAlert').slideDown(600);
  } else {
    $('#ReactivateAlert').slideUp(600);
  }
});
```

```html
        <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="ReactivateAlert" style="display:none">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      When this alert box appears, the margin does not get included in the animation.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="col-form-label col-md-2" for="SelectDemo">Table</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="SelectDemo" name="SelectDemo">
      <option value="">--- Select a Test ---</option>
      <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
      <option value="Test2">Test2</option>
      <option value="Test3">Test3</option>
      <option value="Test4~">Test4~</option>
      <option value="Test5~">Test5~</option>
      <option value="Test6~">Test6~</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm currently sitting at my desk giddily just clicking back and forth between the options repeatedly with a grin on my face. This works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ahahahah. Wonderful! :D